# Set image / background source dynamically

Tags: android

is there any possibility to set background image dynamically?!

I try to explain what I mean.

```
String picVariable = getPictureFromServer();

ImageView image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.dynamic_image);

// I know, that doesn't work, but that's the way I looking for
image.setBackgroundResource(picVariable);
```

Thank you in advance,

Mur

Ps.
I also read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516530/set-source-of-imageview-dynamically-android). It would suggested in one answer, to use java reflection to get a field of the R class by name. But I've never used reflextion before. An example would be very helpfull

Comment: What does `getPictureFromServer` return?

Comment: Something like "abc.png", and there is abc.png in drawables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes I should take a bit more time for searching :)

I found the answer reading [this article](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2009/12/dynamically-retrieving-resources-in.html), and it works fine for me:

```
// The server says, it should be *.png
String picName = getPictureFromServer();
picName = picName.replace(".png", "");

Resources r = getResources();
int picId = r.getIdentifier(picName, "drawable", "com.mypackage.myapp");

ImageView image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.dynamic_image);
image.setBackgroundResource(picId);
```

Answer (score 0):

ImageView does not have any background, but for other widget (like Button), you should use setBackgroundResource(int).

Sorry, I am not sure I read the question correctly... maybe your problem is just that you are trying to use it with a Widget that does not use background ?

Comment: it's not really my project, I just clean errors and add new funktionality. And there is a background for imageviews, but it seems to me very weird as well to use in an imageview a background :)